# Prove that if $E\cap F=\emptyset$ and $X=E\cup F$ then $\int_Xfd\mu=\int_Efd\mu+\int_Ffd\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I did the proof though I didn't use the hypothesis of $X=E\cup F$. Also I didn't see the why of $f$ to be in $\overline{\mathbb R}.$ Could this be any $Y$ space?

Let $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb R}$ be measurable and nonnegative. Prove that if $E,F\in\mathcal A$ are such that $E\cap F=\emptyset$ and $X=E\cup F$ then $$\int_Xfd\mu=\int_Efd\mu+\int_Ffd\mu$$

Proof

$$\int_Efd\mu+\int_Ffd\mu$$ $$=\int_Xf\mathcal X_E d\mu+\int_Xf\mathcal X_Fd\mu$$ $$=\int_X(f)*(\mathcal X_E+\mathcal X_F)d\mu$$ $$=\int_Xfd\mu$$

where the first equality is by definition and the last equality because $E\cap F=\emptyset$ thus when $\mathcal X_E=1,\mathcal X_F=0$ and vice versa.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Consider $X=\underbrace{(0,1)}_{E}\cup \underbrace{(1,2)}_{F},$ and $f(x)=x.$ Is your proof still valid? Also, if you mean $\chi$ to be the indicator function, you shouldn't be looking at the composition of $f$ and $\chi,$ it should be the multiplication of the two.

Comment: its wrong then..  why is wrong?. I meant the multiplication not the composition.

Comment: The indicator function $\chi_E$ is equal to 1 on $E$ and 0 on $X\setminus E.$ So the composition may not even be defined. The multiplication assures that $\chi_E\cdot f$ will take on only the values of $f$ on the set $E,$ and yield $0$ otherwise. Did you try the example I asked you to think about? Try to see what's wrong with your proof based on that example.

Comment: @Chickenmancer yes I did the integrals using the $X=(0,1)\cup (1,2),$ and $f(x)=x$. The integral over $(0,2)$ is $2$ and the other is $2+\frac{1}{2}$ I think I should subtract something on the LHS

Comment: Now, you're trying to show that there is an equality between these two integrals. You've shown how to derive one integral from the other, but you need to make use of your assumptions. Why is it that you can split your integral this way? Why is it that $(f)*(\mathcal X_E+\mathcal X_F)=f?$

Comment: @Chickenmancer Because of the linearity of the integral. And because of definition of $\mathcal X$ and $E\cap F=\emptyset $, when $\mathcal X_E=1,\mathcal X_F=0$; thus would be equal to $f$

Comment: Is the result false right?

Comment: The result is valid. Your proof is correct. The last equality to be true you need  $E\cap F=\emptyset$ and $X=E\cup F$. Writing the last step in details: 

$$\int_X(f)(\mathcal X_E+\mathcal X_F)d\mu$$ 
$$=\int_X(f)(\mathcal X_{E \cup F})d\mu $$ 
$$=\int_Xfd\mu$$

For the first equality you need $E\cap F=\emptyset$ and for the second one, $X=E\cup F$.

Comment: @Ramiro thank you. If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is valid. Your proof is correct. The last equality to be true you need  $E\cap F=\emptyset$ and $X=E\cup F$. Writing the last step in details:

$$\int_X(f)(\mathcal X_E+\mathcal X_F)d\mu$$ 
$$=\int_X(f)(\mathcal X_{E \cup F})d\mu $$ 
$$=\int_Xfd\mu$$

For the first equality you need $E\cap F=\emptyset$ and for the second one, $X=E\cup F$.